# Formula to calculate B-V index?

Tags: luminosity

Is there a formlua or equation to calculate a star's B-V index based on it's observed frequencies in the B and V spectrums ? I have unfortunately not been able to find anything...

Comment: I'd actually say https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23346/24157 is a better match to this question, although that one was closed as a duplicate of a question that's not really related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found :

$$B-V = -2.5 \log_{10} \left(\frac{f_B}{f_V}\right)$$

From [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/how-to-calculate-b-v-colour-index-value-percentage-difference/14062#14062) question. It works for my purposes.

Those are magnitudes on the left. Five magnitudes are a factor of 100, so 2.5 magnitudes are a factor of 10. So if $f_B/f_V =$ 100 (i.e. 10$^2$) then $B-V =$5.

Comment: This is from the standard relationship between flux and magnitude e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_magnitude (Note: $f_B$ here is *flux* in the Bessell/Johnson B filter, not frequency)

Comment: I made a small edit and noted that that's base-10 log. Feel free to edit further if this helps, or roll back if it doesn't. In a few days if nobody leaves an answer you find more helpful, you can also accept your own answer.